# Flood Fill not drawing to canvas

Tags: javascript, html, constructor, p5.js

I have a flood fill algorithm for a drawing application (using p5.js and the editor is brackets), each tool is in its own separate constructor function. I am using javascript and HTML
The problem I am facing is that when the function is called + mouse is pressed, nothing is drawn onto the canvas.

Here is the flood fill js file:

```
function bucketTool() {
    // Set an icon and a name for the object
    this.icon = "assets/bucket.png";
    this.name = "bucket";
    this.selectedColour = null;

    let self = this;

    this.draw = function () {
        if (mouseIsPressed) {
            this.selectedColor = colourP.selectedColour;
            console.log("Mouse pressed");
            console.log("Selected Color:", this.selectedColor);

            loadPixels(); // Load the pixel data
            self.floodFill(mouseX, mouseY, this.selectedColor); 
            updatePixels(); // Update the canvas with the modified pixel data
            console.log(mouseX, mouseY, this.selectedColor);
        }
    };

   
    this.floodFill = function (x, y, replacementColor) {
        if (x < 0 || x >= width || y < 0 || y >= height) {
            return; // Stop if we're outside the canvas boundaries
        }

        const index = (x + y * width) * 4; // Calculate the index in the pixels array
        const pixelColor = [
            pixels[index],
            pixels[index + 1],
            pixels[index + 2],
        ];

        if (JSON.stringify(pixelColor) !== JSON.stringify(replacementColor)) {
            return; // Stop if the current pixel color is not the same as the replacement color
        }

        // Replace the color of the current pixel
        pixels[index] = replacementColor[0];
        pixels[index + 1] = replacementColor[1];
        pixels[index + 2] = replacementColor[2];

        // Recursively fill adjacent pixels
        self.floodFill(x + 1, y, replacementColor);
        self.floodFill(x - 1, y, replacementColor);
        self.floodFill(x, y + 1, replacementColor);
        self.floodFill(x, y -  1, replacementColor);
    };
}
```

In a separate js file the function is initiated, the console log commands work, it is just the no drawing to canvas.

Many thanks.

Have tried adjusting the code a bit, but ended up with a stack overflow (no pun intended!)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you share a runnable [mcve]? How big is the canvas? You can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63840837/6243352) as boilerplate to create a p5 stack snippet. The JS call stack is only a couple thousand deep, so if you have more pixels than that to flood, it'll blow. You might want to write it iteratively, without recursion. Also related: [P5 Flood Fill Attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49226914/p5-flood-fill-attempt)